# Button on JFrame is clickable, but JDialog is up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus, jdialog

Got a JFrame with a Button on it, if the button is pressed then pops a JDialog up.
If i click on the JFrame the JDialog dispose. But if the JDialog is active and I click on the JButton, disposes the JDIalog and open it again. 
I want to close the JDialog also with the JButton.
Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JButton jButton;
    private JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Test");
    private JDialog jDialog;

    public Frame() {
        getContentPane().add(jLabel);
        getContentPane().add(getButton(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton getButton() {
        if (jButton == null) {
            jButton = new JButton("TestButton");
            jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button_Pressed();
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton;
    }

    private JDialog getJDialog() {
        if (jDialog == null) {
            jDialog = new JDialog();
            jDialog.setSize(150, 25);
            jDialog.setUndecorated(true);
            jDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                    jDialog.dispose();
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

                }
            });
        }

        return jDialog;
    }


    protected void button_Pressed() {
        getJDialog().setVisible(true);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just disable the button while the dialog is open.

Comment: You need to show code if you dont want the question to be closed. This site is supposed to be for help with code that you cannot fix yourself and not the more general questions like yours.

Comment: sry added a code sample

Answer (score 0):

The thing is all you're doing is creating the `JDialog` but you forget to give it the reference of your declared `JDialog`, so you can't reference it again. So in your method, instead of this

```
protected void button_Pressed() {
    getJDialog().setVisible(true);        
}
```

Do this

```
 protected void button_Pressed() {
    if (jDialog == null) {
        jDialog = getJDialog();
        jDialog.setVisible(true);
        return;
    }
    if (jDialog.isVisible()) {
        jDialog.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        jDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

**SIDE NOTES**

- Run your Swing apps from the [**Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) like this

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
              new Frame();
          }
      }); 
  }
  ```

  See [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

---

**UPDATE**

There is no point in having the `WindowListener` since you're controlling the flow with the button. get rid of the `jDialog.dispose()` in the `windowClosing` and it works.

Comment: The changes doesn't work it does the same as before.. But thanks

Comment: The problem is if i click on the button when the jdialog is open then it will close the jdialog and open it again

Comment: And when i click on another component it should close too, but that's not the problem only with the button

Comment: What do you mean it only get's in the background. You can dispose instead of `setVisible()`. It will do the same thing. `dispose()` just frees up resources, but does the same thing as `setVisible()`

Comment: Ad I have no idea what this _"And when i click on another component it should close too, but that's not the problem only with the button "_. You have no reference to whatever you're talking about anywhere in your question.